# Error al ejecutar menú con switch dentro de un while

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{

    static float options = -1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        nombre();
        while (options == 0)
        {

           Console.WriteLine("Elige una opcion: \n" +
           "\n1.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n2.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n3.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n4.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n5.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n6.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n7.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n8.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n9.- Opcion1: " +
           "\n10.- Opcion1:\n");
           string options = null;

            options = Console.ReadKey().ToString();

            switch (options)
            {

                case "1":
                    option1();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    option2();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    option3();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    option4();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    option5();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    option6();
                    break;
                case "7":
                    option7();
                    break;
                case "8":
                    option8();
                    break;
                case "9":
                    option9();
                    break;
                case "10":
                    option10();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selecciona una de las opciones dadas!");
                    break;


            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me peta el programa sin salir nada en la consola

> 'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'E:\institut\m3\UF5\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   The thread 0x924 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x1670 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'E:\institut\m3\UF5\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   The thread 0x1c50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x2dfc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[6128] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

estos son los errores que me salen

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate it.

Comment: si, lo siento no me había dado cuenta de que estaba en la pagina española

Comment: Hola Bienvenid@ a [es.SO], te invito a que hagas el [tour] y también leas [ask]. Saludos

Comment: esto no tira miles de errores de compilacion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el menu no se esta ejecutando porque agregaste la condición

```
while (options == 0)
```

y asignaste previamente 'options' como valor -1 (jamas entrara), desconozco el motivo por el que agregas esa condicion, pero si la necesitas, deberias agregar un OR dentro de la sentencia while:

`while (options == 0 || options == -1)`

y el "ReadKey" no permite leer mas de 1 caracter, por tanto, puede ser reemplazado por un "ReadLine", aqui dejo la correccion de tu codigo funcionando:

```
        while (options == 0 || options == -1)
            {

            Console.WriteLine("Elige una opcion: \n" +
            "\n1.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n2.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n3.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n4.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n5.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n6.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n7.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n8.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n9.- Opcion1: " +
            "\n10.- Opcion1:\n");
            string options = null;


            switch (Console.ReadLine())                {

                case "1":
                   // option1();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    //  option2();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    // option3();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    // option4();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    // option5();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    // option6();
                    break;
                case "7":
                    // option7();
                    break;
                case "8":
                    //option8();
                    break;
                case "9":
                    //option9();
                    break;
                case "10":
                    //option9();
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selecciona una de las opciones dadas!");
                    break;


            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }`
```

Comment: oh vale lo del readkey provocaba que no pudiera coger las opciones

Comment: no hay de que :D ,como gran consejo, usa los puntos de interrupcion para depurar el codigo, se aplican en el costado izquierdo (antes del contador de lineas de codigo) y al ejecutar, tu programa se detiene hasta llegar al punto, avanzas linea por linea con 'F10', con 'F11' entras a una funcion o rutina y presionando 'F5' ejecutas todo o hasta llegar a otro punto.
Esto te permite ver el estado de las variables y poder realizar una traza de lo que realmente hace tu codigo! es de gran ayuda esta utilidad, saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! :) <3

Answer (score 0):

estas usando option1(); de esta forma es un metodo y no una variable
si quisieras ejecutar un metodo con ese nombre estaria bien, pero almenos en el codigo no existe y tampoco podes hacer esto

string options = null;

Ya que, ya lo definiste previamente como un static Float!

Comment: tengo declarado el metodo para todas las opciones de esta manera
static void option1(){}